# How to filter elasticsearch by date field with date modification

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

To filter by date, I use the following queries:

```
'body'  => [
    'query' => [
        'bool' => [
             'filter' => [
                  'range' => [
                      'expire_at' => [
                          'gte' => now()
                      ]
                 ]
             ]
         ]
    ]
]
```

UPD: All records have another date field - last_checked. The question is how to select records in which, for example, (expire_at - 7 days) > last_checked?

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
"expire_at" => array(
    "lt" => "now+7d/d"
)
```

Comment: Sorry, I asked the question incorrectly. I have updated the question.  Need to compare not with the current time, but with another date field

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Check the [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#ranges-on-dates) documentation: you can use [date math](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math) in the range parameters. E.g., `expire_at - 7 days < now()` means that the expiration will be within the next 7 days. Then you can do:

```
"range": {
  "expire_at": {
    "lt": "now+7d/d"
  }
}
```

Note that this will include also already expired items. If you want to avoid that, you can add the condition that the expiration date is not met yet:

```
"range": {
  "expire_at": {
    "lt": "now+7d/d",
    "gte": "now/d"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I asked the question incorrectly. I have updated the question.  Need to compare not with the current time, but with another date field